# Finding the value of H when it is given a survival function.

Tags: probability

Given $$S(x) = 1 - \frac{x}{120}, x \in [0, 120].$$

If Thomas dies (now he is 30 years old), his family will get $1000000$ with probability $0.2$. At the beginning of each year Thomas pays premium H with probability $0.8$. $v = \frac {1} {1.06}.$

Next in the formulas: $ _kp_x = \frac {S(k+30)} {S(30)}.$

Determine the premium intensity $H$ by adopting the equivalence principle.

**My solution:**

$H = \frac {0.2 \times 1000000 \times A_{30}} {0.8 \times \ddot a_{30}}$.

The problem is that I cannot calculate $\ddot a_{30}$ or $A_{30}$, because the formulas are:

$\ddot a_{30} = \sum_{k=0}^∞  v^k \times _kp_{30}$ or

$A_{30} = \sum_{k=0}^∞  v^{k+1} \times _kp_{30} \times q_{30+k}.$

So here I have an infinity. I need to find one of these values at least, because I can find the second value using formula $\ddot a_{30} = \frac {1 - A_{30}} {1-v}$. But I do not know how to do that (probably the $S(x)$ need to be used). Maybe I do not know some formulas.

The answer have to be $H=3195.$

Comment: I am not able to relate $S(x)$ with the sum his family gets or the probability with which they will. What am I missing here? Nor do I understand the terms $A_{30}$ and $\ddot{a}_{30}$ in your solution. Can you add some prose to describe them?

Comment: S(x) can be related only with $_kp_{30} = \frac {s(30+k)} {S(30)}.$

Comment: OK..... so what's that?

Comment: The fraction for finding H is correct, my professor started solving this exercise.

Comment: I have a problem only with calculating that sum from 0 to infinity, I am not getting the value.

Comment: Ok. So ${}_{k}p_{30}$ is the probability that a person survives till $k$ years given that he is 30 now? $q_k$ is the probability that he dies at age $k$? What is $v$?

Comment: The second one is that he is now k and dies till k+1

Comment: I still don't know what $v$ is.

Comment: $v= \frac {1} {1.06}$

Comment: You may want to add these details to complete the question. In fact, if you are only keen on the solution, you can pose the minimal question about the infinite sum.

Answer (score 1):

Given that,
$$
\ddot{a}_{30} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k \times \frac{S(30+k)}{S(30)}
$$

Now as $S(30) = 0.75$, the sum is,
$$
\ddot{a}_{30} = \frac{1}{0.75}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k \left( 1 - \frac{30+k}{120}\right) \right)=\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k - \frac{1}{90} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\left(\frac{1}{1.06}\right)^k \right) 
$$

The first sum is a sum to $\infty$ of a GP. The second sum can be obtained from [How to derive the closed form of the sum of $kr^k$
?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/912354/652935)