Confused on iterative approach used in solving this recurrence relation.

Here they tried to solve the recurrence relation $a_{n} = n - 1 - a_{n-1}, a_{0} = 7$ using an iterative approach. I'm confused about the last two steps in this solution and how we went from the 2nd last line to the last line of work.
Kindly please help explain.

Try induction.${}$

or this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/912373

@AnneBauval based on your second comment, I'm not sure how to apply that formula since if you notice as the exponent for the rate , -1, increases, the terms are decreasing by 1 instead of being increased by 1. Do you see what I mean?

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}s^{n-1-k}k=s^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1/s)^kk$

@AnneBauval Sorry could you possibly type up an answer just so I make sure we're on the same page. I'd really appreciate it :)

$(n-1)-(n-2)+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}(n-n)$
is the special case $r=-1$ of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}r^{n-1+k}k$, i.e. of $r^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kr^k$.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kr^k = r\frac{1-nr^{n-1}+ (n-1)r^n}{ (1 - r)^2 }
$$ hence
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1+k}k=\frac{(-1)^n
+2n-1}4=\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor.
$$

Clever solution! Just 1 final question: how'd you figure out to manipulate $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kr^k$ in such a way?

How you though to use $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kr^k$ in the way you did where you converted it into $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}s^{n-1-k}k$

The given sum was $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}s^{n-1-k}k$ for $s=-1$, and I wanted to use the "known" formula for $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}r^kk$, so I factored out $s^{n-1}$, and took $r=s^{-1}$. But you are making me think of an even simpler approach. Let me improve my answer. ... Done

If $n$ is even, then $(n-1)-(n-2)+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}(n-n)$
$=[(n-1)-(n-2)]+[(n-3)-(n-4)]+\cdots+[1-0]=[1]+[1]+\cdots+[1]=\dfrac n2$.
If $n$ is odd, then $(n-1)-(n-2)+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}(n-n)$
$=[(n-1)-(n-2)]+[(n-3)-(n-4)]+\cdots+[2-1]+[0]=[1]+[1]\cdots[1]=\dfrac{n-1}2.$
So the sum is $\dfrac n2-\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{1+(-1)^{n-1}}2\right)$, since the quantity in big parentheses is $0$ when $n$ is even and $1$ when $n$ is odd.
Can you take it from here?

Right but how would I derive the [(2n - 1) + (-1)^n]/4 by myself had I not seen the solution manual give this answer?

I edited to address your comment, @BobMarley

How'd you think of $\left(\dfrac{1+(-1)^{n-1}}2\right)$? Was it just a creative move or some sort of insight into the problem that I'm not seeing here?

@BobMarley:   I have that in my bag of tricks and fine it useful; cf. here, here, and here

Just a side note, another easy way to solve the problem is to generalize from lower index up.
We could see that:
$a_0=7$
$a_1=-7$
$a_2=8$
$a_3=-6$
$a_4=-9$
$a_5=-5$
$a_6=10$.
Clearly there is a pattern for odd index: $-7, -6, -5, ...$ and even index: $7, 8, 9, 10...$. This generalize to
$$a_{2k+1} = -7 + k$$ and $$a_{2k} = 7 + k.$$
Lastly, we must also check if our solution is correct. That is to check if
$$a_{2k+1} + a_{2k} = (2k+1) - 1$$
for odd $n = 2k+1$. And check if,
$$a_{2k} + a_{2k-1} = 2k - 1$$
for even $n = 2k$.
